# Unable to migrate git repository from one git system to another with "zero-padded file modes" error

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to migrate git repository with all its branches and history from TfsGit (which is doesn't feet our requirements any more) to GitLab (which work pretty well) by doing the following:

```
git clone --mirror https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/xxx/_git/project1.git
cd project1.git
git remote add master git@gitlab.com:xxx/project1.git
git push master --mirror
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
remote: error: object 47754c1677d6cfe0bc1623eba181860cbe8c8351:contains zero-padded file modes 
remote: fatal: Error in object 
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
```

I have already moved about 5 project without any issues but this contains some unknown issues which I don't know how to deal with. Please advise.

Comment: maybe it's a stupid question, but is there a huge difference in git versions between those hosts?

Comment: I don't even know how to check, but I have already migrate a lot of project and have issue with one particular project so I guess version is not an issue.